# Drawing line with mouse movement

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm trying to make OpenGL to draw the line.  When I click the left button of my mouse, it will get the first coordinate.  Then when I move my mouse, the second coordinate is the coordinates of my mouse at the same time.  The second coordinate will not be determined until I click the right button.

But there are two questions with my code:

1. It seems that when I even didn't click my left button, there was the line in the screen.
2. I can't determine the second coordinate through clicking the right button.

Here is my code:

```
#include<GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

int m0,n0,m1,n1,ww,hh;
int flag=0;

void DrawPoint(int x,int y){
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2f(x,y);
    glEnd();
}
void BresenhamLine(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2){
    int x,y,delta1,delta2,e;
    delta1=x2-x1;
    delta2=y2-y1;
    int flag=0;
    x=x1;
    y=y1;
    if (abs(delta2)>abs(delta1)){
        flag=1;
    }
   
    int t1=(x2>x1?1:(delta1=-delta1,-1));
    int t2=(y2>y1?1:(delta2=-delta2,-1));
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glVertex2f(x,y);
    if(flag==0){
        e=-delta1;
        while(x!=x2){
            x+=t1;
            e+=2*delta2;
            if(e>=0)
            {
                y+=t2;
                e-=2*delta1;
            }
            glVertex2f(x,y);
        }
    }
    else{
        e=-delta2;
        while(y!=y2)
        {
            y+=t2;
            e+=2*delta1;
            if(e>=0)
            {
                x+=t1;
                e-=2*delta2;
            }
            glVertex2f(x,y);
        }
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
void DrawLine(){
    //bresenhamline
    BresenhamLine(m0,n0,m1,n1);
    glFlush();
}
void myreshape(GLint w,GLint h)
{
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0,(GLfloat)w,0,(GLfloat)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    ww=w;
    hh=h;
}


void mymouse(int button,int state,int x,int y){
    
    if(state==GLUT_DOWN && button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON){
        m0=x;
        n0=hh-y;
        
    }
    
    if(state == GLUT_DOWN && button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON){
        m1=x;
        n1=hh-y;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

void mymotion(int x,int y){
    m1=x;
    n1=hh-y;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void init(){
    glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    glPointSize(3.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, 500,500, 0);
}

void mydisplay(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    DrawLine();
    glFlush();
}
int main(int argc,char**argv){
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutCreateWindow("simple");
    glutDisplayFunc(mydisplay);
    glutMouseFunc(mymouse);
    glutReshapeFunc(myreshape);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(mymotion);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: You should ask one question at a time, read [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: why don't you use GL_LINES?

Comment: ... or [`GL_LINE_STRIP`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. It seems that when I even didn't click my left button, there was the
>    line in the screen.

In `mymotion()`, the current x and y coordinates of the mouse pointer are stored in the `m1` and `n1` variables, which are then used as an endpoint of the drawn line segment in `DrawLine()`. This happens repeatedly, whenever the mouse pointer's position changes, also when neither of the two mouse buttons is pressed down.

---

> 2. I can't determine the second coordinate through clicking the right
>    button.

When you keep the right mouse button pressed, while moving the mouse cursor, the line segment is not moving anymore. So, the program works as intended, but it *somehow* keeps updating `m1` and `n1`, when no mouse buttons are pressed...

The documentation of [glutPassiveMotionFunc()](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node51.html) says:

> glutMotionFunc and glutPassiveMotionFunc set the motion and passive motion callback > respectively for the current window. (...)
> The passive motion callback for a window is called when the mouse
> moves within the window while no mouse buttons are pressed.

So, `mymotion()` could be removed. - Without it, the line segment's end points will no long change when the mouse cursor is moved, they only get updated in `mymouse()`, after a mouse button has been pressed.

---

Side note, in case you're modifying a found GLUT example program: The example's intention is probably to illustrate a 2D concept by drawing a line using [Bresenham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)’s line algorithm with `GL_POINTS`, one vertex for every pixel. That could also be done much simpler and more efficiently by letting OpenGL handle the line rendering, by using `GL_LINES`, for example like this:

```c
void DrawLine(void)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(m0, n0);
    glVertex2f(m1, n1);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```

(`BresenhamLine()` (and `DrawPoint()`) could then also be removed. And by the way, `init()` never gets called, so the clear color and the point size keep their default values.))